# VS Code: Focusing the current editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I've got the following scenario:

- Program maximized with "Explorer" tab and 2 editor tabs open
- (i.e. on windows) I want to peek some website so I split half screen to the browser, half to VS Code.

I want a hotkey that hides the explorer, reduces the size of the unfocused tabs and focuses the main editor tab. Does a think like that exist (or any addon does that?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- By default in VS Code, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> opens/hides the sidebar, of which the File Explorer is a part.
- Also by default, when the main VS Code window is resized, the editors also resize to occupy the same proportions of the viewport.
- `workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup`, the command that focuses the most recently used editor group, doesn't have a keyboard shortcut assigned to it by default, but one can be assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With the hint of that, I found out I could check the avalable "tab" commands by opening the menu (F1), then checking all of the "view:" commands. After some exploring, I found out the "maximize editor group and hide sidebar" which served really well to what I wanted.